# How to create structure in Kafka for delay resending message in topic

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, producer-consumer

Delay producing the message to the topic? If not, will it appear soon?

I have "NQueue" topic for sending differents notifications(Sms, Push, Transactions). I am trying turn a failed message(HttpRequest) back to queue with some delay.

I have already re-read all the documentation and have not found this functionality. If it does exist, or you know how to implement it, then write here, please.

Like:

```
await producer.ProduceAsync(topic, message, delay);
```

Below I will attach a photo of my vision...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering the use of [Kafka Stream](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/), I would suggest to consider the option of using [windowed aggregations](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Windowed+aggregations+over+successively+increasing+timed+windows). In short, as follows:

- create a Kafka topic for failed messages
- build a Kafka Stream app with [windowed aggregations](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Windowed+aggregations+over+successively+increasing+timed+windows) to turn failed messages back to your queue (also be aware of [an ability to suppress consecutive updates](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-328%3A+Ability+to+suppress+updates+for+KTables)). I assume that windowed aggregations will give you the opportunity to delay your failed messages.

In case streams are not suitable for you, look at the [Dead Letter Queues](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-error-handling-dead-letter-queues)